# Solving Exponential Equation $x^2 \cdot 2^{x+1} + 2^{|x-3|+2} = x^2 \cdot 2^{|x-3|+4} + 2^{x-1} $

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

The solution for the Exponential Equation considering $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\boxed{x\in[3, \infty)\cup  \left\{ -\frac12;\frac12 \right\} }$

My try for solving $x^2 \cdot 2^{x+1} + 2^{|x-3|+2} = x^2 \cdot 2^{|x-3|+4} + 2^{x-1} $:

I initially considered that
$$x^2 \cdot b+c=x^2 \cdot d+e \Longrightarrow b=d  \land c=e  $$
Therefore, I would have:
$$2^{x+1}=2^{|x-3|+4} \Longrightarrow x+1=|x-3|+4 \Longrightarrow |x-3|=x-3 $$
$$\text{For  } x-3=x-3 \Longrightarrow x\in(-\infty, \infty) $$
$$\text{For  } -x+3=x-3 \Longrightarrow x=3 $$
$$\text{The interval would be } [3, \infty)$$

The same for
$$2^{|x-3|+2} =2^{x-1} \Longrightarrow |x-3|+2=x-1\Longrightarrow |x-3|=x-3 $$
$$\text{For  } x-3=x-3 \Longrightarrow x\in(-\infty, \infty) $$
$$\text{For  } -x+3=x-3 \Longrightarrow x=3 $$
$$\text{The interval would be } [3, \infty)$$

I don't know how to get $\left\{ -\frac12;\frac12 \right\}$ and I could't perform $$x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{e-c}}{\sqrt{b-d}} $$

This is the wrong approach? Any hints to solve it? Anything would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
x^{2}\times 2^{x+1} + 2^{|x-3| + 2} = x^{2}\times 2^{|x-3|+4} + 2^{x-1} & \Longleftrightarrow 2x^{2}\times 2^{x} + 4\times 2^{|x-3|} = 16x^{2}\times 2^{|x-3|} + \frac{2^{x}}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 4x^{2}\times (2^{x} - 8\times 2^{|x-3|}) = 2^{x} - 8\times 2^{|x-3|}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (4x^{2} - 1)(2^{x} - 8\times 2^{|x-3|}) = 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?